# Why Do I Get [object Object] at Request in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, express

Sending `GET` Request:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
    console.log(`response-text -> ${xhttp.responseText}`);
}
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:3001/get/", true);
xhttp.send("hello world");
```

ExpressJS :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors({origin: '*'}))
app.get('/get/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`Your Request -> ${req.params}`);
})

app.listen(3001);
```

console:

```
response-text -> Your Request -> [object Object]
```

I Even Tried `req.query` & body-parser, But i still get `[object Object]` or `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

`body-parser` is now deprecated, but from **Express v4.16** no additional module is necessary, you can just use the built-in middleware:

```js
app.use(express.json());
```

After that, depending on the data you want to get from the Request object (`req`), access the corresponding property:

- Request **Path Parameters** (`GET '/get/:param'` with `value` as `:param`):

```js
res.send(`Your Request -> ${req.params.param}`);
// or
res.send(`Your Request -> ${req.params['param']}`);
```

- Request **Query Parameters** (`GET '/get?param=value'`):

```js
res.send(`Your Request -> ${req.query.param}`);
// or
res.send(`Your Request -> ${req.query['param']}`);
```

- Request **Body** (`GET '/get/'` with a `body`):

```js
res.send(`Your Request -> ${req.body}`);
```

Comment: Now I Get This : `response-text -> Your Request -> {}` (i used `req.body`)

Comment: @Jaazim because you're not passing any body data in your request. What are you expecting to be shown?